# Unable to apply inner query on PFUser Class in Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

We have a Table name userProfile which has a **pointer userId to User** Table.
We are applying inner query on userProfile

```
               PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserProfile"];
                [query whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
                [query whereKey:@"relation" equalTo:@"Agent"];
                [query includeKey:@"userId"];
                [query includeKey:@"profileId.userId"];
                query.skip = arrProfiles.count;
                query.limit = 15;
                NSString *searchText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.searchBar.text];


                **PFQuery *innerQuery =[PFUser query];
                [innerQuery whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i)%@",searchText]];
                [query whereKey:@"userId" matchesQuery:innerQuery];**



                [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                }];
```

but we are unable to get any results after applying inner query.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, you are saying that the userId has to be equal to the current user. But in the inner query, you are saying that the userId has to match the user with a username entered in the search field.

This means that the query has to satisfy BOTH constraints in order to return results. This can only happen if the current user is literally searching for themselves.

If you are looking for BOTH the current user's profile AND the searched-for profile, you need to use an or query like so:

```
PFQuery *firstQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserProfile"];
[query whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

NSString *searchText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.searchBar.text];

PFQuery *innerQuery =[PFUser query];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"username" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i)%@",searchText]];

PFQuery *secondQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserProfile"];
[secondQuery whereKey:@"userId" matchesQuery:innerQuery];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[firstQuery, secondQuery]];

[query whereKey:@"relation" equalTo:@"Agent"];
[query includeKey:@"profileId.userId"];
query.skip = arrProfiles.count;
query.limit = 15;

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: if i remove the condition userId has to be equal to the current user then also no results.

Comment: Are you sure the userId has a value the currentUser ( pointer to the _User class, not just an objectId)? Are you also sure it isn't being skipped because of the arrProfiles.count is > 0?

Comment: See if we remove the inner query we have the results. query.skip is also 0

Comment: So what are you trying to get? The current user AND the ones searched? If so, you need to create two queries and then combine them with an or query. `[PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1,query2]];`

Comment: `or` query should be on the same class.'